# Closed form bijection between integers and pairs thereof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, closed-form, integers, gaussian-integers

I know that it's simple enough to map the integers, $\mathbb{Z}$, to pairs of integers, $\mathbb{Z}^2$, in a bijective way (i.e. a one-to-one mapping). You can wrap the integers around the origin of the 2D Cartesian grid like a spiral, or you can use some space filling curve, or you can map the integers individually to naturals by "folding up" the real line and then use a common bijection between naturals, like the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) (which is what the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2079816/50421) does).

But so far, I haven't been able to come up with a bijection that has a simple closed form. I know you can express that "folding up" operation using $\mathrm{sgn}$ and $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$, but those seem inelegant, and I'm looking for something that feels more "natural" (no pun intended) to the domain of $\mathbb{Z}$ than mapping them to naturals first, applying a bijection there, and mapping the result back to an integer.

For the positive naturals, there's this very elegant map:

$$ f(a,b) = 2^{a-1}(2b-1) $$

Extending $b$ to the integers is not a problem, but then a) we can't cover $0$ with this, b) we've already covered all other integers, so there's no room left if we want to extend $a$ to the integers as well (which would require changes anyway, since we can't just work with negative powers of $2$ here).

I also can't find anything like a list of common bijections between integers and pairs thereof, I suspect because most mathematicians stop caring after any one bijection has been found.

So my question is, are there any bijections between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$ which can be expressed in a simple closed form, akin to $f$ above, without reducing the problem to the naturals? I'd take a bijection where only one direction of the mapping has a closed form, but if both directions can be expressed in closed form that would be preferable. Bijections that are formulated in terms of the Gaussian integers, $\mathbf{Z}[i]$, instead of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ would also be acceptable.

Comment: What about giving an obvious bijection $\mathbb{Z}^2\to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N}\times \{0,1\}$, then using the one you know for $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ and then finding $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0,1\}\to \mathbb{Z}$ ?(for this last one you can consider $(n,\epsilon)\to 2*n + \epsilon$, I think)