# Does $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ imply $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}^2$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's not like we can say that, because $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the restriction of a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is going also to be a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2$ (although such a bijection may exist). There are other ways to prove that $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}^2$, but is it possible to show this using the fact that $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Can you conclude $\{a,b\}$ is in bijection with $\{a,b\} \times \{a,b \} = \{(a, a), (a,b), (b,a), (b,b)\}$?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot show $\mathbb{N}^2 \simeq \mathbb{N}$ from $\mathbb{R}^2 \simeq \mathbb{R}$, as there is no reason to think the witnessing bijection for the former equivalence sends integer pairs to integers.

You *can* deduce $\mathbb{R}^2 \simeq \mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{N}^2 \simeq \mathbb{N}$ if you know that $\mathbb{R} \simeq 2^{\mathbb{N}}$:

$$\mathbb{R} \simeq 2^{\mathbb{N}} \simeq 2^{\mathbb{N}^2} \simeq 2^{\mathbb{N}} \times 2^{\mathbb{N}} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$$

using the obvious bijections. But not the other way around. But there are even explicit formulas for $\mathbb{N}^2 \simeq \mathbb{N}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120393/4280), e.g., so there is no need for arguments from a harder to show fact.

Comment: But is there no way to show that the existence of infinitely many bijections between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ implies that there exists one that also happens to be a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2$

Comment: @11122345791216212837 no I don’t think that can work.

Comment: It might be worth adding that in general $\mathcal P(A) \simeq \mathcal P(B) \implies A \simeq B$ is independent of ZFC.

Comment: @MeesdeVries That's interesting. Can you give a source for that?

Comment: @11122345791216212837 I only know of these slides: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jbaldwin/asl07.pdf But I'm sure Google could help you out further.

Comment: @11122345791216212837 It is well-known (though rather advanced set theory) that you can have (in ZFC) that $(|\Bbb R|=)2^{\aleph_0} =  2^{\aleph_1}$ while of course $\aleph_0 < \aleph_1$, e.g. in a model of Martin's Axiom for $\aleph_2$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Isn't $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})| = 2^{\aleph_1}$?

Comment: @11122345791216212837 No, not necessarily. Not in that model of ZFC.