# What is an example of function $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$ that is a bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Could you give me an example of function $ f \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ that is both one-to-one and onto? Does this work: $f(n) := n \times (-1)^n$?

N starts with zero.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{N}$ start with one or zero?

Comment: no, that is not onto: there's no $n$ such that $f(n)=1$

Comment: It starts with zero

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1029787/442

Answer (score 29):

First note that $\Bbb{Z}$ contains all negative and positive integers. As such, we can  think of $\Bbb{Z}$ as (more or less) two pieces. Next, we know that every natural number is either odd or even (or zero for some people) so again we can think of $\Bbb{N}$ as being in two pieces. lastly, let's try to make a map that takes advantage of the "two pieces" observation . That is, let's make a function from evens/odds to positives/negatives. Let $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$ where

$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{n}{2} & n\text{ is even} \\
    -\frac{n + 1}{2} & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

This map is a bijection, although I will leave the proof of that up to you.

Comment: what is the inverse image of 0?

Comment: @Ravi , the OP stated $0\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @ yes I got it. My bad

Answer (score 12):

$$f(n) = n\text{th number in the sequence }0, 1, -1, 2, -2, \ldots$$

Answer (score 6):

$$f\colon \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z,
\qquad
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
\quad\dfrac n2\qquad \text{if $n$ is even}\\
-\dfrac {n+1}{2}\quad \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I believe that this function is not one-to-one.  Notice that both f(0) and f(1) evaluate to 0.

Comment: In $\Bbb N$ where do you get $0$??

Comment: @ Bill Province There is no universal agreement about whether to include zero in the set of natural numbers. Some authors begin the natural numbers with $0$, corresponding to the non-negative integers ${0, 1, 2, 3, ...}$, whereas others start with $1$, corresponding to the positive integers ${1, 2, 3, ...}$. I have rule out $0$ in $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Agreed that there is no universal agreement on inclusion of 0 in N.  However, the problem statement clarifies the notion, and includes N starting with 0.

Comment: Oh ok. I missed that line. Thank you. At first I have also posted with $(n+1)$ then changed it..

Answer (score 6):

Here are lots of answers . . . well not really, they are actually all in effect the same.  In each of them we take $f(0)=0$ and I give instructions for the rest.

1. $f(n)=k$ if $n$ is the $k$th prime, $f(n)=-k$ if $n$ is the $k$th non-prime.
2. $f(n)=k$ if $n$ is the $k$th (non-zero) square, $f(n)=-k$ if $n$ is the $k$th non-square.
3. $f(n)=k$ if $n$ is the $k$th power of $2$, $f(n)=-k$ if $n$ is the $k$th non-power of $2$.

. . . and so on . . . not forgetting

4. $f(n)=k$ if $n$ is the $k$th even number, $f(n)=-k$ if $n$ is the $k$th odd number,

which is actually the example already given by many people.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slight modification of OP's suggestion: The function $f(n):=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k k$ is a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) $f:\mathbb{N}_0\to \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5):

$$f(n)=\frac{1-(2n+1)\cos n\pi}4$$

Answer (score 5):

$$f(n)=(-1)^n \left \lceil \frac{n}{2} \right \rceil$$

where $ \lceil x \rceil $ rounds up a real value (see [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)).

Answer (score 4):

$$f(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}  
\frac{n}{2} & n \textrm{ is even,}\\  
\frac{-(n+1)}{2} & n \textrm{ is odd.}
\end{array}  
\right.$$

Hence, $$f(0) = 0,$$ $$f(1) = \frac{-(1+1)}{2} = -1,$$ $$f(2) = \frac{2}{2} = 1,$$ $$f(3) = \frac{-(3+1)}{2} = -2 \cdots$$