# What is an example of a bijective function f: Z to N that isn't piecewise?

Tags: natural-numbers, function-and-relation-composition, ceiling-and-floor-functions, integers

Like without using if even or odd. Like how you can define a bijection $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ by is $f(n)=\lfloor n/2\rfloor\cdot(-1)^n$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "piecewise"?

Comment: @MJD Usually that means the function has multiple definitions, one for each portion of the domain.

Comment: The floor function is defined piecewise, so I'm not sure that "counts".

Comment: What's the problem with “piecewise functions”?

Comment: I was just curious if such a function existed. It seems all of them are piecewise.

Answer (score 2):

If $0\notin \Bbb N$, then
$$\left|2x-\frac12\right|+\frac12$$ works. If not, then subtract $1$ to get $\left|2x-\frac12\right|-\frac12$. To be honest, absolute values have an implicit poecewise-ness to it, but it's hidden away.

Comment: To be fair, $|\cdot|$ is usually defined as a piecewise function.

Comment: Replace it by $\sqrt{x^2}$ then. Then it's hidden even better, in the convention for the square root.

Comment: @PeterFranek That's a good idea. I would not say that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is piecewise.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \max(2x+1,-2x) = {1\over 2} + \max(2x+{1\over 2},-{1 \over 2}-2x) = {1 \over 2} + |2x+{1\over 2}|$.

Then $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

IBWiglin's example, written another way:
$$
A(n) := \frac{(-1)^n(-2n-1)+1}{4}
$$
Then
$$
A(0)=0,
\\
A(1)=1,
\\
A(2)=-1,
\\
A(3)=2,
\\
A(4
)=-2
$$
The inverse of this function can presumably be written in terms of the Lambert W function...

Comment: I tried that Lambert thing, but you need to use a different branch of W for each value ... sort of the ultimate in piecewise writing.

Answer (score 0):

If I can use the absolute value, then, for example, $$2|x|+\frac{1}{2}\frac{x+1/2}{|x+1/2|}+\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exactly answer your question, but I made a function going the opposite direction $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ which is bijective and not implicitly defined piecewise like the example you gave.
$$ f(n)=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1+2n}{4}\cos(\pi n) $$

This is the restriction to $\mathbb{N}$ of the spiral $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined in the complex plane by
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1+2x}{4}e^{ix}$$
which can be extended to a complex analytic function on all of $\mathbb{C}$.