# Proving $\mathbb{Z × N}$ is countable.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

How would I prove that $\mathbb{Z × N}$ is countable? The hint given was to follow to indicated order. Thanks!

Comment: both Z and N are countable

Comment: Prove $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable and then cartesian product of two countable set is countable.

Comment: The point is to prove cartesian product is contable. You can do it trough some kind of zig-zag bijective function between the pairs and $\Bbb N$. Pairs represent points in a plane... think a way to fill the plane with a function. You can start from one corner, in zig-zag, to the infinity, including jumps to negative values of $\Bbb Z$. Be creative my friend :)

Comment: ...or if you have already proved that $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$ is countable, then use subset of a countable set is countable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bijecting a countably infinite set $S$ and its cartesian product $S \times S$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16611/bijecting-a-countably-infinite-set-s-and-its-cartesian-product-s-times-s)

Answer (score 3):

Let $p_0,p_1,p_2$ be three distinct positive primes. I am taking
$\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$.

Define $\phi:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$ by $\phi(n) = \begin{cases} (n_1,n_2+1), & n = p_0^0p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2} \\
(-n_1,n_2+1), & n = p_0^1p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2} \\
(0,1), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$.

We see that $\phi(p_0^0p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2-1}) = (n_1,n_2)$, $\phi(p_0^1p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2-1}) = (-n_1,n_2)$, hence $\phi$ is surjective.
It follows that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Comment: @user236182: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @user236182: Thanks again.

Comment: @user236182: I don't get the 'you haven't edited...' part of your last comment, $n_2 \ge 0$ so $\phi$ is OK, and the part showing surjectivity seems fine?

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
\mathbb{Z}&\searrow&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
&10&\searrow&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
&5&11&\searrow&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
&2&6&12&\searrow&\vdots&\vdots\\
&1&3&7&13&\downarrow&\vdots&\hspace{1in}\mathbb{N}\\\hline
&4&8&14&\swarrow&\vdots&\vdots\\
&9&15&\swarrow&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
&16&\swarrow&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
&\swarrow&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\end{array}$$